# Unable to run the app on iPod

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have an app which successfully runs on iPhone which has iOS 7.1 . But when I changed the deployment target to 6.1 and I tried to run the app on my iPod touch ,it is giving me the following error

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t> >::sync()", referenced from:
 vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > in LibXL
```

Could you please tell me what could be the wrong?

Comment: Project->Target->Build Setting->Valid Architectures -> add arm64. try this

Comment: it has already arm64  armv7 armv7s. Should I just enter only arm64?

Comment: Build Active Architecture Only set to No

Comment: It is set to NO,but the error still occurs.